# Java used heap constantly increasing

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory, heap-memory

I'm using visualvm to check my springboot application used memory. And while the heap allocated is 450M initially and starts using around 100M, it is constantly using more and more heap memory. When I perform garbage collection, it goes back to 100M, but continues increasing over time. Is this behaviour expected?

BTW: My springboot app has got a lot of controllers (20 or 30), working with Orientdb (not JPA, manually querying and connecting to it).

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no (memory leak). Profiling can answer such questions.

Comment: @lexicore How do I interpret the profiling data? I see objects of type byte, char, String and a lot more, constantly increasing in size.

Comment: What you are describing is not unusual.

Comment: @Michael Profiling is an art of its own. I'd suggest that you google some tutorials.
I'd try to record the allocated objects for a period of time and then check where they are allocated. This normally gives some hints on what is going on.

Comment: @lexicore Ok thanks, I will.

Comment: @user3344003 you mean object instances constantly increasing?

Comment: @Michael Also look first not for the primitives or `String`s but for instances of classes from *your* packages or from Spring packages. I personally love profiling. It's like reading Arthur Conan Doyle.

Comment: You create objects, the heap goes up. You do garbage collection, the heap goes down. You create objects, the heap goes back up. Is the logical memory allocated constantly increasing?

Comment: This is normal unless you're getting out of memory exceptions when the heap is full.  If it GCs and goes back down it's totally normal.